# systemd-path service not working

Tags: linux, systemd, inotify

I have added systemd service to monitor a path. But it is not working. I touched a .txt file under /tmp/test/. But it is not kicking in my service. I cant see "/tmp/testlog.txt" getting generated. Is there anything wrong in my service?

myservice.path

```
[Unit]
Description=Path Exists

[Path]
PathExistsGlob=/tmp/test/*.txt
PathChanged=/tmp/test/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

myservice.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Test

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'mkdir /tmp/test && sleep 60'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo "Test Success" >> /tmp/testlog.txt & '

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

tmp dir:

```
# ls /tmp/test/
ab.txt
#
```

What could be the reason for the failure?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If systemd is an off topic, why do you have systemd as a tag?

Comment: Cf. Tag guidelines: _Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a timing issue. I added dependency and made this service to start as the very last one. That one solved the issue.